# Math notation $\int f(x)\,dx$ vs. physics notation $\int dx\,f(x)$.

Tags: integration, notation, soft-question, physics

In math, the notation of an integral is usually like

$$\int_u^v\!\!\int_a^b\!\!f(x,y)\,dx\,dy\tag{math}$$
where $\int$ and $dx$ are acting as brackets around the function to be integrated.  In physics however, a common notation is

$$\int_u^v\!\!\!dy\int_a^b\!\!\!dx\,f(x,y) \tag{phys}$$

What's the purpose of these different notations, and from where do they originate?

The math notation that surrounds the expression to be integrated looks reasonable, whereas the physics notation assumes that one knows how far the expression extends.  The physics notation maked it easier to associate variable and rage resp. area (if present) associated to the integral, which might be siperior if the integrand is very complex; however complicated integrands are also not uncommon in math.

Comment: What you calll the physics notation is exactly the same as the mathematics one after one applies, in case it is possible, several results that allow a multiple integral to be expressed as iterated integrals. You can check Fubini's Theorem in Google.

Comment: The physics notation follows an operator logic... the operator $(\int_a^b dx)$ is applied to the function $f(x,y)$, anf the operator $(\int_u^v) dy)$ is then applied to the result.

Comment: When you have large expressions in the integral and many iterated integrals the physics notation is perhaps easier to read in terms of which variable is integrated over which range.

Comment: Is this a duplicate question?  I have answered it before, but do not see how to search for it.

Comment: @GEdgar: Not unlikely, but I cound not find a similar question+answer.

Comment: @GEdgar I cannot find the duplicate where you say you have answered it.  I am also much interested in a defensible answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this question has been addressed.  I would be happy to see a pointer to a duplicate that has been answered.

The problem with ***not*** delimiting the integrand on both left and right is that ambiguities that have different values can result.

Which is it?

$$ \int\limits_{a}^{b} dx \, f(x)+c = \int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x)+c \, dx $$

or

$$ \int\limits_{a}^{b} dx \, f(x)+c = \int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx + c $$

Because you cannot tell if that added term is part of the function being integrated or is not part of it.

The OP calls this the *"physics notation"*.  I dunno if that is what the source, but this notation is flawed.  Why would people do this?  What is gained by it?

Comment: One possible benefit of this notation is that when integrating an expression with multiple variables (very common in physics), putting the differential first tells you right away what you're integrating with respect to, which might focus the problem.

Comment: If you need brackets, write brackets. The "physics" notation is no more ambiguous than the $\sum$ and $\prod$ notations.

Comment: In fact I would not write the "math" integral the way you did on the right-hand side of the first equation. I would write $\int_a^b (f(x) + c)\,\mathrm dx$. See how the integral of a sum of functions is written [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumRule.html), for example.

Comment: @Integrand , about the order of integration, it's always that the $\int$ on the left is associated with the $dx_n$ on the right.  It ***encloses*** the other integrals.

Comment: I understand; I mean something like $\int_0^5 dT \frac{mM (T_1+T_2)}{r^2+T^2}$ lets you know immediately that this integral is with respect to $T$.

Comment: @DavidK I agree that some added parenths or brackets will clear it up.  I just don't see that added requirement as an advantage.  $$ $$ And you're right about the $\sum$ and $\prod$ notes, sometimes parenths will be needed, but I still don't see that as a good justification for what just appears to me to be ***wrong*** notation with integrals.

Comment: @DavidK, would you write $$ \int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x)+g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$ as $$ \int\limits_{a}^{b} \big( f(x)+g(x) \big) \, \mathrm{d}x $$ in all cases?

Comment: BTW, using the `\mathrm{d}x` notation ($\mathrm{d}x$) for a differential is something I had never seen before about a decade (or maybe two) ago.  None of my college textbooks in mathematics, physics, or electrical engineering used that, but I think it's a ***good*** notation both in integrals and derivatives (Leibniz notation).  I thought maybe that came from textbooks and lit from the UK and Europe.  Where did that come from?

Comment: I learned about the $\mathrm dx$ on MSE. It took me a while to warm up to it, but now I feel like I'm being sloppy when I type $dx$. It was presented as an ISO standard when I read about it. I don't know where it came from before that.

Comment: Would I put the brackets around the sum in the integral in all cases? Maybe not, but then I sometimes catch myself writing things like $a/bc$ when I mean $a/(bc)$.